# Can sneak attack damage from Wracking Touch be used to power spellthief abilities?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, sneak-attack

As a druid, I am trying to achieve some synergy with a spellthief in my party. I would like to prepare Wracking Touch, then let the spellthief steal it so that she can use the sneak attack damage to power spellthief abilities like Steal Spell etc. However, I am not sure RAW supports this use of Wracking Touch.

**Wracking Touch (Complete Adventurer p158):**

> In addition, if you have the sneak attack ability, you also deal sneak attack damage to the affected creature unless the creature is immune to extra damage from critical hits.
>
> ...
>
> Unlike a normal use of sneak attack, your target need not be flanked or denied its Dexterity bonus to take sneak attack damage from this spell.

**Steal Spell (Complete Adventurer p13):**

> A spellthief who hits an opponent with a successful sneak attack can choose to forgo dealing 1d6 points of sneak attack damage and instead steal a spell, or the potential to cast a specific known spell, from his target.

Does dealing sneak attack damage through Wracking Touch count as a "successful sneak attack" for the purposes of Steal Spell?

Feel free to also point out any other problems with this tactic that I might have missed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s ambiguous, but I’d allow it.

The phrase “unlike a *normal* use of sneak attack” implies to me that this *is* using sneak attack, not just getting bonus damage that happens to be equal to your sneak attack. And the spellthief is an exceedingly weak class, so I have no problem reading things in their favor.

Comment: I'm not sure either answer is clearly correct, so I'm accepting this one for "It's ambiguous".

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the CAdv in front of me right now, but from what you posted I would say no.

> In addition, if you have the sneak attack ability, **you also deal sneak attack damage to the affected creature** unless the creature is immune to extra damage from critical hits.

To me that does not mean you are doing a sneak attack, just applying your sneak attack dice to the Wracking Touch. I would read the second part, about the target not needing to be denied its Dex bonus, as just clarifying that the sneak attack damage is added whether or not you could normally apply it.